# Is it possible to re-open a file after close() without creating it again in the same java program?

Tags: java

I have to figure out a way to re-open a file that was initially an output file in order to make my program work.

My program needs to read from the input file first and then write to an output file.

Then I will prompt the user to enter code here`e option to input more or search any data from the output file.

My program starts with the option to 1-Insert more data, 2-Search Data, 3-Quit program.

I could close the I/O files after the user has input more data, but what if the user wants to search data first?

```
 if(readFile==0)
            {
                FileReader inFile = new FileReader("DATA4STUDENTS.txt");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inFile);

                FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter("PASSED_STUDENTS.txt");
                BufferedWriter bw1= new BufferedWriter(fw1);//Files i want to write and read again later on in the same program. 

                FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter("FAILED_STUDENTS.txt");
                BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);

                PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(bw1);
                PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter(bw2);
                pw1.print("STUDENT ID\t"+"SUBJECT CODE\t"+"CARRY MARK\t"+"STATUS\t"+"FINAL EXAM\t"+"STATUS\t"+"TOTAL MARK\t"+"STATUS\t"+"GRADE\t"+"GRADE SCORE");
                pw1.println();

                pw2.print("STUDENT ID\t"+"SUBJECT CODE\t"+"CARRY MARK\t"+"STATUS\t"+"FINAL EXAM\t"+"STATUS\t"+"TOTAL MARK\t"+"STATUS\t"+"GRADE\t"+"GRADE SCORE");
                pw2.println();   
                int index=0;
                Assessment [] a = new Assessment[100];
                Assessment [] b = new Assessment[100];
                double[] CM=new double[100]; //array for CarryMark
                double[] FM= new double[100]; //array for FullMark
                boolean[] PG=new boolean[100]; //array for Passing-Grade
                while(((inData=br.readLine()) !=null))
                {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inData,"#");
                    StudName=st.nextToken();
                    StudID=st.nextToken();
                    SubName=st.nextToken();
                    FullOn=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    FullEX=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    mark=Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                    fullM=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    EMark=Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                    fullEM=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

                    a[index]=new Ongoing_Assessment(StudName, StudID, SubName,FullOn, FullEX, mark, fullM);
                    b[index]=new Final_Exam_Assessment(StudName, StudID, SubName,FullOn,FullEX,EMark, fullEM);
                    if(a[index] instanceof Ongoing_Assessment)
                    {
                        Ongoing_Assessment OA=(Ongoing_Assessment) a[index];
                        CM[index]=OA.getFinalMark();
                    }
                    if(b[index] instanceof Final_Exam_Assessment)
                    {
                        Final_Exam_Assessment FEA=(Final_Exam_Assessment) b[index];
                        FM[index]=FEA.getFinalMark();
                    }

                    if((CM[index]+FM[index])>=a[index].PassingGrade())
                    {
                        PG[index]=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PG[index]=false;
                    }
                    index++;
                }

                for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
                {
                    String mss=" ";
                    String mss1=" ";
                    String mss2=" ";
                    String grade=" ";
                    double grade2=0.00;
                    if(PG[i])
                    {
                        mss="PASS";                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mss="FAIL";
                    }
                    if(a[i] instanceof Ongoing_Assessment)
                    {
                        Ongoing_Assessment OA=(Ongoing_Assessment) a[i];
                        mss1=OA.toString();
                    }
                    if(b[i] instanceof Final_Exam_Assessment)
                    {
                        Final_Exam_Assessment FEA=(Final_Exam_Assessment) b[i];
                        mss2=FEA.toString();
                    }
                    if(mss.equals("PASS"))
                    {
                        if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=91 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=100)
                        {
                            grade="A+";
                            grade2=4.00;
                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=80 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=90)
                        {
                            grade="A";
                            grade2=4.00;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=75 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=79)
                        {
                            grade="A-";
                            grade2=3.67;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=70 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=74)
                        {
                            grade="B+";
                            grade2=3.33;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=65 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=69)
                        {
                            grade="B";
                            grade2=3.00;
                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=60 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=64)
                        {
                            grade="B-";
                            grade2=2.67;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=55 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=59)
                        {
                            grade="C+";
                            grade2=2.33;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=50 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=54)
                        {
                            grade="C";
                            grade2=2.00;

                        }
                    }
                    else if(mss.equals("FAIL"))
                    {
                        if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=47 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=49)
                        {
                            grade="C-";
                            grade2=1.67;
                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=44 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=46)
                        {
                            grade="D+";
                            grade2=1.33;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=40 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=43)
                        { 
                            grade="D";
                            grade2=1.00;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=30 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=39)
                        {
                            grade="E";
                            grade2=0.67;

                        }
                        else if((CM[i]+FM[i])>=0 &&(CM[i]+FM[i])<=29)
                        {
                            grade="F";
                            grade2=0.00;

                        }
                    }
                    if(mss.equals("PASS"))
                    {
                        **strong text**pw1.print(mss1+mss2+"\t"+df.format((CM[i]+FM[i]))+"%\t\t"+mss+"\t"+grade+"\t"+df.format(grade2));
                        pw1.println();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pw2.print(mss1+mss2+"\t"+df.format((CM[i]+FM[i]))+"%"+mss+"\t"+grade+"\t"+df.format(grade2));
                        pw2.println();
                    }
                }
                br.close();
                pw1.close();
                pw2.close();
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It is really lengthy though. But, alright

Comment: don't need to post *all* code, just the relevant file I/O parts

Comment: Whoops. Sent the whole code. My bad.

Comment: no that's not too much, its fine

Comment: The FileChannel in Java NIO may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Files cannot be reopened after they are closed. There is no way do that without recreating a object.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347891/10818862 for more information.